# Magento custom module configuration groups not collapsed

Tags: magento

I'm developing a custom module for Magento and I have created a configuration page for it with several groups of fields. It works ok so far but I understand that these groups should be collapsed by default but mine are all expanded when the page is loaded and only collapse when the user collapses them.

My system.xml file:

```
<config>
    <tabs>
            <mymoduletab translate="label" module="mymodule">
                    <label>My Module</label>
                    <sort_order>400</sort_order>
            </mymoduletab>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
            <mymoduleoptions translate="label" module="mymodule">
                    <label>My Module Options</label>
                    <tab>mymoduletab</tab>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                    <groups>
                            <basicoptions translate="label">
                                    <label>Basic Options</label>
                                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                    <fields>...
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks. The documentation for Magento development I've been able to find are just sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the state of the groups is saved in the database when you save the configuration values. If you save the values with the groups open they'll be open by default, even after logging out and logging back in. I couldn't find where they are saved.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you just have to add the following to the group you want open:

```
<expanded>1</expanded>
```